# Strange grammar in cat command

Tags: bash, cat

First of all, I apologize if this question can be answered with a web search, but I couldn't find anything.

There is some grammar in the cat command which I've seen to "repeat" files.

```
cat file{,}
```

Is equivalent to calling

```
cat file file
```

Also,

```
cat file{,}{,}{,}{,}
```

repeats `file` not four times, but 16 times.
In addition,

```
cat file{,,}
```

repeats `file` 3 times.

I would like to know more about this grammar.  What is it called?  Is it built into cat or is it a shell feature?  Are there more features of this grammar?

Comment: Alas, no one pointed it put, but this grammar has nothing to do with `cat`. It works on every command; it is a feature of the shell. See for example how `echo {1,2}{3,4}{5,6,7}` outputs a lot of combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is called [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Generally you can write `file{1,2,3}` and bash expands it to `file1 file2 file3` before running the command.

If you write

```
mkdir foo{1,2,3}{a,b}
```

it will be equivalent to

```
mkdir foo1a foo1b foo2a foo2b foo3a foo3b
```

and will create those 6 directories.

In your case (`{,}`) you are adding nothing and nothing and therefore get the same word twice.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax that you are referring to is known as [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

The `{,,}` syntax is often used to repeat words.  Saying:

```
echo foo{,,}
```

would produce

```
foo foo foo
```

When you combine brace expansions, it's equivalent to *nesting* those:

```
echo foo{,}{,}{,}
```

is *equivalent* to saying

```
echo foo\ foo{,}{,}
```

and to

```
echo foo\ foo\ foo\ foo{,}
```

and produces

```
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

Essentially, *n* pairs of `{,}` after a given string would generate the string 2<sup>n</sup> times.

In addition to link mentioned above, you can also learn about brace expansion [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace).