# Delete lines if string does not appear exactly thrice

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a CSV file that contains a few thousand lines. It looks something like this:

```
abc,123,hello,world
abc,124,goodbye,turtles
def,100,apples,pears
....
```

I want each unique entry in column one to be repeated exactly three times. For example: If exactly three lines have "abc" in the first column that is fine and nothing happens. But if there is not exactly three lines with "abc" in the first column, all lines with "abc" in column 1 must be deleted.

This

```
abc,123,hello,world
abc,124,goodbye,turtles
abc,167,cat,dog
def,100,apples,pears
def,10,foo,bar
ghi,2,one,two
ghi,6,three,four
ghi,4,five,six
ghi,9,seven,eight
```

Should become:

```
abc,123,hello,world
abc,124,goodbye,turtles
abc,167,cat,dog
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: before/after example pls. `all lines with "abc" in column 1 must be deleted` is not clear. all duplicated or really **all**?

Comment: @Kent, I really want **all** columns deleted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk way

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]==3' test{,}
```

- Set Field separator to `,`
- Whilst first file

  - Increment array with field 1 as key
  - Skip next instruction
- Read file again

  - If the array counter is 3 print

Comment: What is this `test{,}` ? Filename?

Comment: @AvinashRaj this expands `test{,}` to `test test`. See [Strange grammar in cat command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22434207/1983854)

Comment: thanks, @fedorqui . And why he used `FNR==NR` where there is a single file?

Comment: @AvinashRaj because `FNR==NR` indicates that you are processing the first file. `awk` does not know if it is the same file or not, it just takes into account the position of them in the command line. So when you say `FNR==NR {whatever}` you are saying: when you are processing the first file, do `whatever`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am using the same file twice, that is the reason for the `test{,}`, every comma adds another file to the args. The reason i read the same file twice is that the first time i count occurrences and the second time i print based on the count.

Answer (score 5):

this awk one-liner should do:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]==3' file file
```

it doesn't require your file to be sorted.

Comment: @Jidder `NR==FNR and FNR==NR` ..:)